# Failing import in python using kivy

Tags: kivy

python code

```
   from kivy.app import App
   from kivy.uix.label import Label


   class MyApp(App):

       def build(self):
           return Label(text='Hello world')


   if __name__ == '__main__':
       MyApp().run()
```

The results

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\Programs\Mobapps\main-1.py", line 4, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Users\mchip\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 425, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Users\mchip\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 249, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Users\mchip\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Bezier, BorderImage, Ellipse, \
 ImportError: cannot import name 'SmoothRectangle' from 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions' (C:\Users\mchip\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\kivy\graphics\vertex_instructions.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and the full traceback error.